# Am I receiving tensorflow 2.x warnings while using version 1.14?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very simple question. I recently had to format my pc and therefore I recreated my whole working environment. I'm using Anaconda (latest version) and I used conda to install tensorflow-gpu, keras..

The code, like before, is working fine but I'm seeing a lot of warnings about deprecations and I'm sure a lot of them are related to tf version 2.x but I'm using tf 1.14 (I printed it after importing tensorflow in my code and so I'm sure, moreover I never asked Anaconda to install any 2.x version)

For example:

```
W0813 19:25:46.491560 15288 nn_ops.py:4224] Large dropout rate: 0.75 (>0.5). 
In TensorFlow 2.x, dropout() uses dropout rate instead of keep_prob. 
Please ensure that this is intended.

W0813 19:36:22.136491 15288 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] 
From C:\Users\-----\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_GPU\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:850: 
The name tf.summary.merge_all is deprecated. 
Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all instead.
```

Is this normal? Do I have to correct them or can I disable this types of warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of these warning messages is to spread awareness of TensorFlow 2.0
Because in the long run TF 2.X is likely to be widely adopted.
This is normal and you can safely ignore these warnings by,

```py
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
```

Comment: Apologies. I have updated my code snippet can you please check now?

Comment: Yes but doesn't this remove all warnings? I this case it is a good solution but only if your code is 100% ok

Comment: Well this is trade-off on suppressing log messages. It will not suppress all warning logs but a majority of them.